# Dynamics of population development - how is this equation derived?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading a publication on an ecological model, where the authors adopt the following growth equation:

$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} = \bar{r}n(t)\left(1-\frac{n(t)}{K} \right) \tag{1}$$

where $\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}$ is the rate of change for the time-dependent population density $n(t)$ for $t=0,....,T$, $\bar{r}$ is an average growth rate, and $K$ is a fixed population density limit. If we assume a starting population density $n(t=0)=n_0$, the authors give the following equation for the time-dependent population density:

$$n(t)=\frac{Kn_0\exp(\bar{r}t)}{K+n_0(\exp(\bar{r}t)-1)} \tag{2}$$

Now, I have tested this equation against a simple numerical scheme where I incremented the growth rate and population size, and did indeed obtain the same results, so this equation does seem correct. My question is how the authors obtained it. I assume they started off something like this:

$$n(t)=n_0+\int_0^t\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}dt \tag{3}$$

But how to continue from here? Where does the exponential in Equation (2) come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a separable equation, which can be solved via partial fractions.
$$
r(t+c)=\int\frac{((K-n)+n)\,dn}{n(K-n)}=\ln|n|-\ln|K-n|
$$

It is also a Bernoulli equation with a quadratic term, so can be solved via the substitution $u=n^{-1}$,
$$
u'=-n^{-2}n'=-r(u-K^{-1})\implies u(t)-K^{-1}=(u(0)-K^{-1})e^{-rt}
$$

Both approaches lead quickly to the given solution.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either method (my background is not in mathematics), and I struggle to see how I can apply the two pieces of information you provided. Could you please provide a brief pointer as to how to get started applying on of these methods? Or do you know of a source which details a similar derivation?

Comment: You can look at any place that discusses the logistic equation. It is the most simple of the population dynamic models. And thus also one of the more unrealistic, I hope the publication is some kind of introduction into the topic, in a research paper it should be no more than a side-note.

Comment: I did indeed find a source which seems to illustrate the process: https://jmahaffy.sdsu.edu/courses/f06/math636/lectures/competition2/solnlogistic.html#bernoulli . The algorithm in the paper is indeed quite simple and has a few questionable assumptions even I as a non-ecologist can spot (such as the time-averaged growth rate), but for my purposes it will simply serve as an example test case for an inference algorithm. Thanks for the heads-up, though!